# Date table column Sum and differencer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datatable

i need to make a data table like that:

```
Subjects          old        new    diff
Sub_1             10         50     40
Sub_2             30         10     -20
total             40         60     20
```

this is a part of code

```
DataTable subjects = new DataTable();
subjects.Columns.Add("Subjects");
subjects.Columns.Add("old");
subjects.Columns.Add("new");
subjects.Columns.Add("diff");
subjects.Rows.Add("Sub_1", sub1.Old, sub1.New, (sub1.New - sub1.Old));
subjects.Rows.Add("Sub_2", sub2.Old, sub2.New, (sub2.New - sub2.Old));
subjects.Rows.Add("Total", .. total of above    .. , .. total of above    .., .. total of above  ..);
```

so i need to  ask how to calculate the total value of last column ( Total) , and is there is any other way to calculate the 4th coulmn ( 3rdcol - 2 2nd col )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have declared your columns without DataType(thanks to @*Steve* for comment). So, please change `Add()` methods as:

```
subjects.Columns.Add("old", typeof(Int32));
subjects.Columns.Add("new", typeof(Int32));
```

Also, you can set the value for `diff` column like this:

```
subjects.Columns.Add("diff", typeof(Int32), "new - old");
```

And, then remove any other calculations in `Rows.Add` method:

```
subjects.Rows.Add("Sub_1", sub1.Old, sub1.New);
subjects.Rows.Add("Sub_2", sub2.Old, sub2.New);
```

And then you can use `DataTable.Compute(string expression, string filter)` method. It computes the given expression on the current rows that pass the filter criteria.
In your case expression will be `Sum(columnName)` and the filter will be empty string, because you don't need any filter.

```
subjects.Compute("Sum(old)", "")
```

So, change your code as:

```
subjects.Rows.Add("Total",
                   subjects.Compute("Sum(old)", ""), 
                   subjects.Compute("Sum(new)", ""),
                   subjects.Compute("Sum(diff)", ""));
```

Comment: You are correct in your example, but the code posted by the OP has a big error and if it is not fixed then also your solution cannot work. The columns are declared without datatype and thus they are created as strings. Sum cannot work on them. Also the diff column could be created with an expression property set (New-Old), then your answer will work and with less code

Comment: Thanks aloooot :) for your support  ... .
i tried it and the code is working

Comment: `subjects.Columns.Add("diff", typeof(Int32), "New - Old");` and remove any added value for  that column like the final Compute on it

Comment: @DevFady I have updated question as Steve suggested.

Comment: @Steve thanks alooot for supoort :) but i habe another that in real datatable this isnt the last column so when i use this code subjects.Rows.Add("Sub_1", sub1.Old, sub1.New, (sub1.New - sub1.Old) , another value ); i cant add the "another value "  and when i use subjects.Rows.Add("Sub_1", sub1.Old, sub1.New, "diff", another value ); sooo is there is any other solution for this ??

Comment: @DevFady You must not include `diff` in `Add` method. Its value will be calculated automatically. Change your code as:
`subjects.Rows.Add("Sub_1", sub1.Old, sub1.New, another value)`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev yes i know this solution but in my case i need their order to be as i said to is there is any way to exclude this column when i add the values to row ??

Comment: @DevFady You can use `DataColumn.SetOrdinal` method. For example: `dataTable.Columns["diff"].SetOrdinal(5);` and `dataTable.Columns["another_column"].SetOrdinal(4);`